# MongoDB 3.4 Server not starting with bind error following a CentOS 7.4 security update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, centos, centos-7

MongoDB 3.4 server is failing to start following a CentOS security update and reboot.

No configuration changes made. The previous update and reboot a couple of days earlier did not cause any problems. Could the CentOS update be the reason for the problem?

Many thanks, any thoughts are much appreciated!

#### Error messages in mongod.log

```
E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Cannot assign requested address for socket: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017
E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets
```

#### The CentOS upgrade installed before the reboot

```
Installed:
  kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.17.1.el7                                                                                               

Updated:
  binutils.x86_64 0:2.25.1-32.base.el7_4.2                  device-mapper-persistent-data.x86_64 0:0.7.0-0.1.rc6.el7_4.1           
  dhclient.x86_64 12:4.2.5-58.el7.centos.1                  dhcp-common.x86_64 12:4.2.5-58.el7.centos.1                            
  dhcp-libs.x86_64 12:4.2.5-58.el7.centos.1                 initscripts.x86_64 0:9.49.39-1.el7_4.1                                 
  kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.17.1.el7               kernel-tools.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.17.1.el7                              
  kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.17.1.el7            kmod.x86_64 0:20-15.el7_4.7                                            
  kmod-libs.x86_64 0:20-15.el7_4.7                          kpartx.x86_64 0:0.4.9-111.el7_4.2                                      
  libdb.x86_64 0:5.3.21-21.el7_4                            libdb-utils.x86_64 0:5.3.21-21.el7_4                                   
  libgudev1.x86_64 0:219-42.el7_4.6                         net-snmp-libs.x86_64 1:5.7.2-28.el7_4.1                                
  systemd.x86_64 0:219-42.el7_4.6                           systemd-libs.x86_64 0:219-42.el7_4.6                                   
  systemd-sysv.x86_64 0:219-42.el7_4.6                      tuned.noarch 0:2.8.0-5.el7_4.2
```

Comment: Hmmm, firewalld releated. There's a bespoke zone that didn't include the server's ip. Seems all working after I included the server's own IP address in that zone. Still have no explanation since I didn't make any changes to the firewall configuration or mongod neither were those packages included in the last CentOS update.

Answer (score 1):

@smile2day, It's pretty clear from your error log

> E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Cannot assign
>   requested address for socket: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017

There is MongoDB 3.4 Server startup problem resist through bind() of IP, not from your  `CentOS update`.

May be you have mistake of configuration of code. As i am able to see here in one straight line you are writing the `bindIp` with `port` number.

As MongoDB BOL documented 
[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) should be separated in `systemLog` of `mongod` settings like such as

```
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response and your thought - very much appreciated. 

mongod.conf included bindIp: 127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and the port.  mongod failed to start until I added the external IP as a source to the firewalld zone I've setup for mongo (the server is part of a replica set). 

Unexplained is that mongod started up fine after previous system updates. No configuration changes to the system (including firewalld)  were made since.